# How to find the difference of time in hours between local time and user-defined time?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub parkingcharge {

    sub exittime
    {
        ($sec, $min, $hour) = localtime();
        print "exit time:$hour:$min:$sec\n";
    }

    my $exit  = exittime();
    my $entry = "9:10:8";

    print "\nvehicle entry time is :$entry\n";
    print "\nvehicle exit time is :$exit\n";

    my $parkingCharge = ($entry - $exit);

    print "\ntotal parking charge is : $parkingCharge\n";
}

parkingcharge();
```

The output appears like this

```
exit time:5:46:57

vehicle entry time is :9:10:8

vehicle exit time is :1

total parking charge is : 8
```

I want to find the parking charge in a Perl vehicle management program. The rate is $2 per hour, so I want to find the difference between entry time and exit time in hours and multiply by 2. The code I have written produces the wrong result.

How to take the difference between times in hours?

Comment: I suggest you use the DateTime package: http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.41/lib/DateTime.pm

Comment: Defining a named sub inside a sub is wrong.

Comment: Do you really have times in the format `9:10:8`? Where in the world is it that a time with `hour:minute:second` does not have leading zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), which is included with Perl. It gives you a convenient way to parse dates into Time::Piece objects, which are essentially epoch timestamps with syntactic sugar. The nice thing about them is that you can use them in math and you'll get seconds.

Because you only have times, we need to have the same date for both the entry and the exit time. One way to do that would be to check today's date and use it in both variables. But it's easier to just leave it out. Time::Piece will assume it's `1970-01-01`, which is fine, because we don't care. It's only important that both timestamps have the same date as long as you cannot park over night.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $entry = Time::Piece->strptime( '9:10:8', '%H:%M:%S' );
```

We use [the `strptime` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece#Date-Parsing) to parse the entry time. The second argument is a pattern of [placeholders](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime). `%H` is hours in 24 hour notation, `%M` is minutes and `%S` is seconds. This also works without the leading zeroes.

We now have an entry date of `1970-01-01 09:10:08`, or `Thu Jan  1 09:10:08 1970` if you just `print $entry`.

Next we need to get the exit time.

```
my ( $sec, $min, $hour ) = localtime;
my $exit = Time::Piece->strptime( "$hour:$min:$sec", '%H:%M:%S' );
```

Because just using `localtime` in scalar context would give us today's date, we have to do an extra step. Your code already got the seconds, minutes and hours of this moment. We just use that as a string in the right format and feed it into `strptime` the same way we did for `$entry`. Now we have the exit timestamp, which is `Thu Jan  1 14:46:56 1970` while I write this.

Getting the duration is a simple matter of subtraction. Converting it to hours is just a division by 60 for minutes and by 60 for hours.

```
my $duration = $exit - $entry;
my $duration_in_hours = $duration / 60 / 60;
```

The `$duration_in_hours` is `5.61333333333333` for me right now. If you want people to pay for every started hour, you'd have to round up.

```
my $fee_started_hours = int( $duration_in_hours + 1 ) * $hourly_fee;
```

I prefer to only pay for full hours of parking, so I'd like rounding down more.

```
my $fee_full_hours = int( $duration_in_hours ) * $hourly_fee;
```